# Return some attributes only in detail view in django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have an attribute I want to expose in my API. Calculating this attribute is costly, so I want to make this available only in the detail view (aka `/api/foo/1/`) and not list view(aka `/api/foo/`).

How can I do this with tastypie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the "use_in" resource field attribute, which has the options of "all", "list" and "detail".

You can read about it more [here](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#use-in)